# Play facebook video from url in react native

Tags: reactjs, facebook, react-native, embedded-video

I am building an app where user will be able to play facebook videos from urls that I will provide.

Is there a way to embade facebook videos in react-native from url?

I have tried using react-native-video, react-facebook-player

React-facebook-player only works in react app. In react-native it gives an error that can not resolve div.

Can I wrap react-facebook-player component within Webview?
If so how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use react-native-webview
eg:

```js
<WebView
              style={{height: videoHeight}}
              source={{uri: 'https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=VIDEOID HERE'}}
              
            />
```